# Finding a recursive formula for combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, tiling

I need help with a HW question.

**EDIT**
you can rotate and reflect

#### Question

> Let $f(n)$ denote the number of different ways to fill the shape $2 \times n$ with the $2$ shapes below:
> [image]

> find recursion formula for $f(n)$

#### My attempt

$f(1)=1$

$f(2)=2$ because:

[image]

$f(3)=5$ because:

[image]

for $n\ge 4$ ,I want to express $f(n)$ with $f(j)$ for $j<n$. So I tried to fill part of the shape and understand the formula, but every time I think about it from the start to check my answer - I get a different recursion formula.

I added below a part of my sketch for better understaning my difficulty solve the problem:
[image]

Thank you!

#### EDIT:Attempt 2

[image]

#### EDIT:Attempt 3

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're off to a decent start.  The top 2 drawings are essentially duplicates.  The lower right one isn't quite finished.   You'll want to complete the rectangle at the left.  You mentioned you got a different answer.  What did you get for an answer?

Comment: It also looks like your L shapes are a reflection of what you were given, although, I don't think it should change the answer as long as you stay consistent.

Comment: There are additional cases, e.g. when $n = 3$ there are at least two more cases, obtained by reflecting the $L$-shaped cases.

Comment: @Mike  I edited my post. I added another attempt and the answer is $f(n-1)+f(n-2)+4f(n-3)+2f(n-4)$

Comment: I see that you've stated reflections are allowed.  In that case, the equation looks good, but you may want to rethink your base cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the $2 \times (n-1)$ case, both the figures are stating the same case. So if you have already constructed a $2 \times (n-1)$ board, then to get to the $2 \times n$ board you just need to add the rectangular tile in the end. Thus far, it gives us:
   $$f(n)=f(n-1)+\text{other ways to construct a }2 \times n \text{ board}.$$
2. Now consider the other case, where you have a $2 \times (n-3)$ board already constructed. And you have to fill the $2 \times 3$ vacant spaces to tile the $2 \times n$ board. You have considered two possibilities in your diagram and they are independent of each other. But there can be more. For example, you can have the following:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}&\\
r&r&\color{red}{l}
\end{array}, \qquad 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}{l}&r&r\\
\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}
\end{array}, \qquad 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}\\
\color{red}{l}&r&r
\end{array}, \qquad 
\begin{array}{ccc}
r&r&\color{red}{l}\\
\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}&\color{red}{l}
\end{array}
$$
Thus we will have $4$ independent ways to complete the tiling. So,
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+4f(n-3)+\text{(think: is this it? or do we need any more cases, e.g. $2 \times (n-2)$?)}$$

Comment: I suggest : f(n)= f(n-1)+f(n-2)+2f(n-3)

Comment: I get $f(n) = 2 f(n - 4) + 4 f(n - 3) + 2 f(n - 2) + f(n - 1)$. :)

Comment: Assuming that reflections don't count, only rotations, 2 of those cases won't work.  I think @Lourrran is close, but missed a case.

Comment: I missed a case ? ? ?

Comment: I see, in the case when one doesn't consider reflections and only rotations indeed the recurrence is $f(n) = f(n - 4) + 2f(n - 3) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 1)$. @Lourrran the $f(n - 4)$ term comes from the combination of two $L$-shaped tiles to form a $2$ by $4$ section.

Comment: Ok, exact. And we need to initiate also f(0)=1 to apply this recurrence.

Comment: Right, $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: @prcssngnr I edited my post - you can rotate and reflect.

Comment: @prcssngnr I get $f(n-1)+f(n-2)+4f(n-3)+2f(n-4)$ . You got $2f(n-2)$, why is that? you can look at my post again, I added a drawing of all the cases I could think of.

Comment: @Lior In the case where reflections are allowed then you get as you said, i.e. $2f(n - 4) + 4f(n - 3) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 1)$. That factor $2$ that I had should not be in there.

Comment: @prcssngnr Thank you.